# Microblogging/RSS generator with tag support

Tags: notification, rss

I'm trying to create something like https://status.github.com/ or https://status.heroku.com/

We use email mostly for notifications right now, but that's gross because most of the time you don't even care and they just end out getting filtered and ignored.

I would like to have something that

- Supports tags
- Supports RSS (or atom)
- Supports RSS on a per-tag, or perhaps on a set of tags basis

It would be nice if it could have a current status indicator, but that's not (strictly speaking) necessary.

Is there something like that out there? Free is nice, but commercial might be OK, too.

Comment: I have a question, if you want to create something like Github and Heroku status pages. Does it mean you want to create status page for your company (website, app, service (API))? The page will tell your customer what the current status and the past incidents. Because when I was reading your question you need a notification system via RSS that supports tagging.

Comment: Not precisely - right now most publication of updates is done via email. Sometimes people get left out. It seems preferable to not do that.

Comment: So, thing what you need is microblogging or RSS notification like Github and Heroku status pages?

Comment: @Shokatsuryō correct